# How to delete chat user in Quickblox?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, quickblox

In my chat application, user get created after user login to application and I want to delete user using REST API.

As per documentation, here is CURL request to delete user.

```
curl -X DELETE \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" \
-H "QB-Token: b284ddf44f5369611fe14e0e588f1cfa855116c8" \
 https://api.quickblox.com/users/36.json
```

But how to generate QB-Token?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`QB-Token` is your `Session` token . You have to save it when creating a session with user .

```
 QB.createSession({login: user.login, password: user.pass}, function(err, res) {      
    token = res.token;     
}
```

Use this `token` for further Api calls .

Comment: Can an admin user delete a casual user? Here in the doc its just given " A user can delete himself from the platform. " https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/js-users#delete-user